# elf dynstr garbage collector

Tags: linux, firefox

I am trying to figure out whats the purpose of **elf dynstr garbage collector** is when compiling Firefox 3.6?

I have tried to build with both `--enable-elf-dynstr-gc` and `--disable-elf-dynstr-gc` the size of the files is exactly the same.

Any suggestions on what the purpose of **elf dynstr garbage collector** is and if it is best to enable or disable it?

Answer (score 0):

This program is supposed to remove unused strings from the .dynstr section of ELF binaries ([see the comment in the source](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/config/elf-dynstr-gc.c#3)) As far as I know, it's disabled by default nowadays, and doesn't even work on 64-bit builds, so I don't think it's terribly important. Yes, Mozilla has a lot of outdated configure options and legacy code. No, it's not important to poke around at them and try to find the cheat codes. The default settings have been pretty well tested and odds are they're what you want to use. Release Firefox builds are built with [a pretty minimal set of options](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/0a796d07499a/browser/config/mozconfigs/linux32/release). Why would we leave out a bunch of things that would make the browser faster or smaller?